# How to Integrate ringdroid fork into my Android app

Tags: android, eclipse, android-manifest

here is the repo https://github.com/mitch000001/ringdroid

so run git clone https://github.com/mitch000001/ringdroid   to copy on your local.

My question im having a slight issue getting this to work in my Android app.  The end goal is to have my host app use ringdroid as a library project so i can make calls to it as if it were apart of my host app.  My host app would be thus dependent on ringdroid project.

What i have done is imported ringdroid as its own project into eclipse.  then i set this project to be a library (have to change one switch statement to if statement, no big deal). then on my host android project's properties i add ringdroid as a library.  I want to be able to start ringdroid on the press of a button from within my host app.

In my host app activity manifest file i define the ringdroid activity i want to call:

```
 <activity android:name="com.Ringdroid.RingdroidSelectActivity"
                  android:label="@string/main_activity_label">

        </activity>
```

then in my host project i have a button that i want to click that would start this activity but i keep getting a null pointer exception in onCreate of RingdroidSelectActivity. Can one of you  run it and see what im doing wrong ?? keep in mind i have not altered the manifest file of the .RingdroidSelectActivity project except for removing the launcher category.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.... In android you can add another project as a dependency of your own.  What you have to do is define the depenedent activity your calling in the host apps manifest.  I also had to put the permissions there as well.

It seems in ADT 20 the manifest are merged.  I am using an older eclipse and ADT version so i had to merge the manifest myself.